# POSIX fopen(NULL,"r")

Tags: c, io, posix, fopen

I wonder, if it is legimate to call fopen with NULL filename. If it is, It saves me 2 lines of code. On my GNU/Linux machine it works, but It have to be portable. I looked POSIX [fopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html), but it says nothing about this case. Is it undefined behavior?

Comment: Saves you 2 lines of code doing what? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I have function, that may return some filename, or null, if it fails to get it. I do not differ, whether filename is null(cant fetch it), or it refers to non-exist or non-readable file.

Comment: You don't *have* to have extra lines, if you want to get nasty: `FILE *f; if(!filename || !(f = fopen(filename, "r"))) { return NULL; }`

Comment: Nevermind. If I am allowed to pass NULL to fopen, it will make my code cleaner. Am I?

Comment: I think it's much much clearer to express that in an `if` statement than let it happen implicitly. Think about the maintainers.

Comment: Well, to me, it pretty intuitive for me `fopen(NULL)` return NULL.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious if you think about it. What if the maintainer of your code does not think about it and always assumes that the value passed into `fopen` is a string. I say spend 2 lines making it obvious.

Comment: It's hardly likely to be portable. Don't be evil. I run code on a lot of different unixes, and I haven't tried fopen specifically, but from experience there's always one platform that segfaults when you pass NULL to library functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the C standard (from 1999):

7.1.4 Use of library functions

Clause 1:

```
Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise
in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an
invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a
pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a
pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not
const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with
variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.
```

The description of `fopen()` in that same standard does not mention `NULL` or `null pointer` at all.

So, per the C standard, passing `NULL` as filename string pointer to `fopen()` leads to unefined behavior.

POSIX may extend the behavior, however.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX seems to have a defined meaning for this case

> [ENOENT]
>   A component of filename does not name an existing file or filename is an empty string.

so you could return a pointer to (a static) `""` instead of a null pointer.

Comment: It creates problems in other places -- I can pass NULL to free, but not static string. Btw, I use gnulib, but I do not know, does it actually check for this case.

Comment: You can use a non-static string as well, if needed, but would then have to allocate it each time (`malloc(1)` looks a bit silly!).

Comment: Yeah, It hurts intuition of C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

As [Alexey points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621203/1175714), when the behavior of a NULL argument is unspecified, that almost certainly means the behavior is undefined. But I want to add to that since there are legitimate reasons why you'd want to cleanly roll it into a single expression.

You could write a function:

```
FILE *
fopen_safe(char const *fname, char const *mode)
{
    if(fname == NULL)
        return NULL;

    return fopen(fname, mode);
}
```

or a macro if you'd like to avoid the overhead of a function call:

```
#define fopen_safe(fname, mode) \
    ( ((fname) == NULL) ? (NULL) : (fopen((fname), (mode))) )
```

Comment: When writing a macro, always take care to wrap arguments in parens to guarantee the behavior you expect under all circumstances. One unfortunate drawback to macros is that there is no easy way to prevent unwanted side effects, e.g. if you have a macro and a function both named `square`, then `square(++x)` and `(square)(++x)` will have different behavior. The former (the macro) will give you `(x + 1) * (x + 2)` and the latter (the function) will give you `(x + 1)^2`. Of course the obvious solution on the caller's end is to avoid mutating arguments inside macro calls.