# strcasecmp NULL argument; man strcasecmp

Tags: c, string

I made a small program that sigsegved on `strcasecmp`, and had no idea why until I made this test case:

```
strcasecmp(NULL, "TEST");
```

which, when compiled, got me the following warning:

```
test.c:9:4: warning: null argument where non-null required (argument 1) [-Wnonnull]
```

However, `man strcasecmp` doesn't say anything about `NULL` arguments, could someone please explain how I could deduce this theoretically from reading documentation, as opposed to empirically writing test cases? Is it a deeper-rooted standard? Or maybe `const char *` doesn't have the right to be `NULL`, for some reason I don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nobody has actually explained why this is the case yet.

It it *undefined behaviour*. Why?

> Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated otherwise
>   in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to a function has an
>   invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of the function, or a
>   pointer outside the address space of the program, or a null pointer, or a
>   pointer to non-modifiable storage when the corresponding parameter is not
>   const-qualified) or a type (after promotion) not expected by a function with
>   variable number of arguments, the behavior is undefined.

(C standard, 7.1.4)

Since strcasecmp never mentions NULL, it is outside the domain of the function. So the function is free to do as it pleases. Including crash.

(Note: my source here is this related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12621203/1180785)

Answer (score 0):

String compare `strcasecmp` requires 2 parameters, both with non-null strings. Since both are pointers, NULL is also valid. However strcasecmp could have been defined as:

```
int strcasecmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) __attribute__((nonnull));
```

This attribute will produce warnings if at least one argument is NULL.

Comment: I found it with my test case. However, my question is more "why does it require non-null strings, as the man says nothing about it?". Thanks.

Comment: You can not acces NULL memory address, It is obvious that both address may not null. There should be some compiler attributes explicitely or implicitely that says that both parameters may not be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's assumed you have a rough idea of the consequences.  You will have a similar experience if you try this, which uses a non-`NULL` argument:

```
strcasecmp((const char *)1, "A string");
```

Comment: Except this one is almost *always* undefined regardless of whether the function accepts nulls. This is a non-null, invalid pointer.